# XMLHttpRequest cannot load Chrome error JQuery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting this error in chrome

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ttp://www.officeyoganyc.com/lists/?p=subscribe. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

I am attempting to create an AJAX signup form with PHP list.

the signup form works if it simply posts to the ?p=subscribe url, but when I use the JQuery AJAX call it loads the success message, but the request does not go through.

```
<form id="newsletter"  method="post" action="ttp://www.officeyoganyc.com/lists/?p=subscribe" name="subscribeform"><input type="hidden" name="formtoken" value="a7d1884b463ed70e91fb62a5121e9846" />


<div class="fieldHolder">
  <div class="attributeinput1"><input type=text name=email value="email" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="on" size="12"/> 
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">addFieldToCheck("email","Email");</script></div> 
  </div>


  <div class="fieldHolder2">
  <div class="attributeinput2"><input type=text name=emailconfirm value="confirm email" autocomplete="off" size="12"/> 
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">addFieldToCheck("emailconfirm","Confirm your email address");</script></div>
        </div> 
  <input type="hidden" name="list[1]" value="signup"><input type="hidden" name="listname[1]" value="office yoga list"/><div style="display:none"><input type="text" name="VerificationCodeX" value="" size="20"></div>

<div id="subscribe"><input type=image src="http://www.officeyoganyc.com/themes/zen/zen/images/yogaSubmit.png" id="go" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe"></div>
    </form>


  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#go').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#newsletter').serialize(),
                    url: $('#newsletter').attr('action'),
                    success: alert('yes'),
                })


                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You'll also probably want to remove that last comma after `success: alert('yes')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first line misses an `h` in `http`.

```
<form id="newsletter"  method="post" action="ttp://www.officeyoganyc.com/lists/?p=subscribe" name="subscribeform"><input type="hidden" name="formtoken" value="a7d1884b463ed70e91fb62a5121e9846" />
```

should be

```
<form id="newsletter"  method="post" action="http://www.officeyoganyc.com/lists/?p=subscribe" name="subscribeform"><input type="hidden" name="formtoken" value="a7d1884b463ed70e91fb62a5121e9846" />
```

Comment: <s>I don't know if its his ONLY problem, but read the error: it says it cannot load "ttp:// etc", and then it goes on to say it support only the "http" protocol (as opposed to "ttp"). I'd say this is the problem that causes that error.</s> (reacting to a deleted comment?)

Comment: I fixed the stupid error yet it still does not work.  Showing no errors in firebug and still getting a success message.

Comment: after comparing headers between my ajax page that did not work and the standard phplist submit form i found that the name value pair <input type=submit name="subscribe" value="Subscribe" onClick="return checkform();"> were not going through. so i added them into a hidden input and it now works. possibly because of "return false" in the ajax call. but it works now

Answer (score 0):

It's restriction of Same origin Policy

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

EDIT: Nope... you forgot to add h before your address

```
<form id="newsletter"  method="post" action="/lists/?p=subscribe" name="subscribeform"><input type="hidden" name="formtoken" value="a7d1884b463ed70e91fb62a5121e9846" />
```